# Bootstrap 4 popover JS ошибка

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, input

Сначала делаю фокус в `input` и если следующий клик это `label` для этого инпута, то вылетает ошибка в консоль:

> Uncaught Error: Tooltip is transitioning
>       at u.h.show (bootstrap.min.js:7)
>       at u.h._enter (bootstrap.min.js:7)
>       at HTMLInputElement. (bootstrap.min.js:7)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLInputElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3)
>       at Object.trigger (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)
>       at Object.simulate (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)
>       at HTMLDocument.c (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4t9ovvvx/)

Как исправить?

Comment: А где в документации говорится про trigger: 'focusin'? Такого не нашел просто.

Comment: @YozhEzhi а как вызвать поповер по фокусу?

Comment: @bsbak, попробуй добавить инпуту `data-animation="false"` пишут это помогает и сама проверила с ним ошибка не вылазит , https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21607

Comment: @Elena да, спасибо, работает...